Will Tordon on roots kill the tree, or the root?
I was digging a water ditch and I have no trees within 30 feet of it. Yet, I still have 1 inch roots in the ground. I'm not sure what trees put out these roots and how far away they are. But I'd like them gone. If I put Tordon in the root will that kill the root, or the entire tree? How potent is it?
The reason why I want these roots gone is because I know they pop up these little sproutling trees that I've been dealing with for years.

Since they sprout, can you tell us what the tree is? Wouldn't it be safer to chop as you go?

It seems like a/the main active ingredient in Tordon is picloram.   Wikipedia has this to say - "Picloram can be sprayed on foliage, injected into plants, applied to cut surfaces, or placed at the base of the plant where it will leach to the roots. Once absorbed by the foliage, stem, or roots, picloram is transported throughout the plant. "
So yes, if you put it on the roots of tree it will spread throughout the tree and kill it.    It looks to be moderately toxic, but more importantly it is long lived and the data sheet says not to use it in water intended for irrigation or domestic purposes - Specifically https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/agrian-cg-fs1-production/pdfs/Tordon_22K_Label1h.pdf states (second last paragraph on page 2) "To avoid injury to crops or other desirable plants, do not
treat or allow spray drift or run-off to fall onto banks or bottoms of
irrigation ditches, either dry or containing water, or other channels that
carry water that may be used for irrigation or domestic purposes" - so maybe this is not a great solution for use in a water ditch. (although I suspect if you are going to put a pipe that does not have holes in the ditch it could work).
That datasheets I've read indicate it is very potent - so a small amount can have a large blast radius.
As far as I can tel Tordon is a brand name - and depending on what you buy it could very well include other nasty herbicides as well.   You might want to investigate which one you intend to purchase and advise its active ingredients as it is quite possible it will have other affects.

Picloram (Tordon) can have a fairly long half-life in the soil - anywhere from 1 week to four months, depending on soil temps, rainfall and activity from soil microorganisms.
